# Facebook Graph API post message with link to page's wall

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

My problem is: When I post to page's wall some message with link it shows as Posted By Others, without link it shows normally in page timeline (Im group's admin ).

[image: When I post to page]

The same code posts to my timeline just fine:
[image: When i post to my wall]

I use AS3 library.
My permissions:

```
"publish_stream", "user_photos","publish_actions","manage_pages"
```

my post code:

```
var params:Object = new Object();
params.message = messageTextInput.text;
params.description = "description";
params.caption = "caption";
params.name = "name";
params.link = "http://www.ya.ru";
params.picture = "http://image.bayimg.com/cajchaado.jpg";
FacebookDesktop.api(page.id+"/feed", onCallApi, params, "POST"); //use POST to send data (as per Facebook documentation)
```

Facebook documentation says I can post either link or message, but it works just fine, except of showing in "Recent posts by others" ( please see attached screenshot ).

[image: How post looks like in Recent Posts by Others popup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post on a fanpage on behalf of itself (not the user), you have to use the **page access token**.

What happening is- when you make the call, the sdk uses the default token (user token), so the post is published on behalf of the user which is displayed in the "*Recent Post by Others*" section in the page.

Since you have requested for `manage_pages` already in your code, you can simply obtain the page access token with this call- `/{page-id}?fields=access_token`. Use this token with your current call just by adding the parameter `access_token`-

```
....
params.picture = "http://image.bayimg.com/cajchaado.jpg";
params.access_token = "{page-access-token}";
....
```

Comment: wow. great answer, thanks! It doesn't explain why message posting works just fine and image posting too. But I will check it just right away!

Comment: Am not surey just message works, but conceptually it must not. To post on page behalf always use page token